# OpenSSL Client Certification "rsa routines:int_rsa_verify:wrong signature length error" (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I have followed the guides here: https://arcweb.co/securing-websites-nginx-and-client-side-certificate-authentication-linux/ and here: https://www.djouxtech.net/posts/nginx-client-certificate-authentication/ to setup Client Certification authentication (with CRL) for my home network on Raspbian. However when using both methods (starting fresh each time) i get the following error in the Nginx access log (with a HTTP 400 response to the client):

```
2021/01/03 13:35:32 [alert] 26452#26452: *10 ignoring stale global SSL error (SSL: error:04091077:rsa routines:int_rsa_verify:wrong signature length error:0D0C5006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:EVP lib) while waiting for request, client: 192.168.1.1, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2021/01/03 13:35:32 [info] 26452#26452: *10 client SSL certificate verify error: (8:CRL signature failure) while reading client request headers, client: 192.168.1.1, server: ****, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "***"
```

I do already have Client Certificates working using this guide: https://gist.github.com/rkaramandi/20a04a41536f3d7e6d2f26b0b9605ab6 but i wanted to move to having a more maintainable system with a CRL to make certificate maintenance easier.

My Nginx config for the site is:

```
    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  ***;
    
    
    #added for client cert auth
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/ca/certs/cacert.pem;
    #    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ca.crt; #The working non-CRL CA
        ssl_crl /etc/ssl/ca/crl/ca.crl;
        ssl_verify_client optional;
        ssl_verify_depth 2;
    
        ssl on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    #added for client cert auth
    
        location / {
            # SSL client verification is optional in general but not for the front end, so I can use other apps without client certificates.
            if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
                return 403;
            }
    
            proxy_pass http://***;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect http:// https://;
    
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/***/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/***/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
    }
```

I can't seem to find any solutions to the error i am seeing other than to start again. I have tried generating the client certificates with 2048 and 4096 key lengths but this doesn't seem to fix the problem.
I tried generating a client certificate and revoking it just to see if the CRL worked and it seemed to but i still get the length error:

```
2021/01/03 13:52:19 [alert] 27291#27291: *4 ignoring stale global SSL error (SSL: error:04091077:rsa routines:int_rsa_verify:wrong signature length error:0D0C5006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:EVP lib) while waiting for request, client: 192.168.1.1, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2021/01/03 13:52:19 [info] 27291#27291: *4 client SSL certificate verify error: (23:certificate revoked) while reading client request headers, client: 192.168.1.1, server: ***, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "***"
```

I have also tried commenting out most lines in the Nginx site config file with no impact so i think this is an issue with the certificates being generated using OpenSSL as opposed to a Nginx issue.

My openssl.cnf file used is below in case there is a part not mentioned in the guides causing an issue:

```
    #
    # OpenSSL example configuration file.
    # This is mostly being used for generation of certificate requests.
    #
    
    # Note that you can include other files from the main configuration
    # file using the .include directive.
    #.include filename
    
    # This definition stops the following lines choking if HOME isn't
    # defined.
    HOME            = .
    
    # Extra OBJECT IDENTIFIER info:
    #oid_file       = $ENV::HOME/.oid
    oid_section     = new_oids
    
    # System default
    openssl_conf = default_conf
    
    # To use this configuration file with the "-extfile" option of the
    # "openssl x509" utility, name here the section containing the
    # X.509v3 extensions to use:
    # extensions        =
    # (Alternatively, use a configuration file that has only
    # X.509v3 extensions in its main [= default] section.)
    
    [ new_oids ]
    
    # We can add new OIDs in here for use by 'ca', 'req' and 'ts'.
    # Add a simple OID like this:
    # testoid1=1.2.3.4
    # Or use config file substitution like this:
    # testoid2=${testoid1}.5.6
    
    # Policies used by the TSA examples.
    tsa_policy1 = 1.2.3.4.1
    tsa_policy2 = 1.2.3.4.5.6
    tsa_policy3 = 1.2.3.4.5.7
    
    ####################################################################
    [ ca ]
    default_ca  = CA_default        # The default ca section
    
    ####################################################################
    [ CA_default ]
    
    dir     = /etc/ssl/ca       # Where everything is kept
    certs       = $dir/certs        # Where the issued certs are kept
    crl_dir     = $dir/crl      # Where the issued crl are kept
    database    = $dir/index.txt    # database index file.
    #unique_subject = no            # Set to 'no' to allow creation of
                        # several certs with same subject.
    new_certs_dir   = $dir/certs        # default place for new certs.
    
    certificate = $dir/ca.crt       # The CA certificate
    serial      = $dir/serial       # The current serial number
    crlnumber   = $dir/crlnumber    # the current crl number
                        # must be commented out to leave a V1 CRL
    crl     = $dir/crl.pem      # The current CRL
    private_key = $dir/private/ca.key   # The private key
    RANDFILE    = $dir/private/.rand    # Private random file number
    
    x509_extensions = usr_cert      # The extensions to add to the cert
    
    # Comment out the following two lines for the "traditional"
    # (and highly broken) format.
    name_opt    = ca_default        # Subject Name options
    cert_opt    = ca_default        # Certificate field options
    
    # Extension copying option: use with caution.
    # copy_extensions = copy
    
    # Extensions to add to a CRL. Note: Netscape communicator chokes on V2 CRLs
    # so this is commented out by default to leave a V1 CRL.
    # crlnumber must also be commented out to leave a V1 CRL.
    # crl_extensions    = crl_ext
    
    default_days    = 365           # how long to certify for
    default_crl_days= 300           # how long before next CRL
    default_md  = default       # use public key default MD
    preserve    = no            # keep passed DN ordering
    
    # A few difference way of specifying how similar the request should look
    # For type CA, the listed attributes must be the same, and the optional
    # and supplied fields are just that :-)
    policy      = policy_match
    
    # For the CA policy
    [ policy_match ]
    countryName     = match
    stateOrProvinceName = match
    organizationName    = match
    organizationalUnitName  = optional
    commonName      = supplied
    emailAddress        = optional
    
    # For the 'anything' policy
    # At this point in time, you must list all acceptable 'object'
    # types.
    [ policy_anything ]
    countryName     = optional
    stateOrProvinceName = optional
    localityName        = optional
    organizationName    = optional
    organizationalUnitName  = optional
    commonName      = supplied
    emailAddress        = optional
    
    ####################################################################
    [ req ]
    default_bits        = 2048
    default_keyfile     = privkey.pem
    distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
    attributes      = req_attributes
    x509_extensions = v3_ca # The extensions to add to the self signed cert
    
    # Passwords for private keys if not present they will be prompted for
    # input_password = secret
    # output_password = secret
    
    # This sets a mask for permitted string types. There are several options.
    # default: PrintableString, T61String, BMPString.
    # pkix   : PrintableString, BMPString (PKIX recommendation before 2004)
    # utf8only: only UTF8Strings (PKIX recommendation after 2004).
    # nombstr : PrintableString, T61String (no BMPStrings or UTF8Strings).
    # MASK:XXXX a literal mask value.
    # WARNING: ancient versions of Netscape crash on BMPStrings or UTF8Strings.
    string_mask = utf8only
    
    # req_extensions = v3_req # The extensions to add to a certificate request
    
    [ req_distinguished_name ]
    countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
    countryName_default     = AU
    countryName_min         = 2
    countryName_max         = 2
    
    stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
    stateOrProvinceName_default = ***
    
    localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)
    localityName_default        = ***
    
    0.organizationName      = Organization Name (eg, company)
    0.organizationName_default  = ***
    
    # we can do this but it is not needed normally :-)
    #1.organizationName     = Second Organization Name (eg, company)
    #1.organizationName_default = World Wide Web Pty Ltd
    
    organizationalUnitName      = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
    #organizationalUnitName_default =
    
    commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
    commonName_default      = ***
    commonName_max          = 64
    
    emailAddress            = Email Address
    emailAddress_max        = 64
    
    # SET-ex3           = SET extension number 3
    
    [ req_attributes ]
    challengePassword       = A challenge password
    challengePassword_min       = 4
    challengePassword_max       = 20
    
    unstructuredName        = An optional company name
    
    [ usr_cert ]
    
    # These extensions are added when 'ca' signs a request.
    
    # This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
    # requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.
    
    basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
    
    # Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
    # the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.
    
    # This is OK for an SSL server.
    # nsCertType            = server
    
    # For an object signing certificate this would be used.
    # nsCertType = objsign
    
    # For normal client use this is typical
    # nsCertType = client, email
    
    # and for everything including object signing:
    # nsCertType = client, email, objsign
    
    # This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
    # keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
    
    # This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
    nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"
    
    # PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
    subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
    authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
    
    # This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
    # Import the email address.
    # subjectAltName=email:copy
    # An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
    # deprecated according to PKIX.
    # subjectAltName=email:move
    
    # Copy subject details
    # issuerAltName=issuer:copy
    
    #nsCaRevocationUrl      = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
    #nsBaseUrl
    #nsRevocationUrl
    #nsRenewalUrl
    #nsCaPolicyUrl
    #nsSslServerName
    
    # This is required for TSA certificates.
    # extendedKeyUsage = critical,timeStamping
    
    [ v3_req ]
    
    # Extensions to add to a certificate request
    
    basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
    keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
    
    [ v3_ca ]
    
    
    # Extensions for a typical CA
    
    
    # PKIX recommendation.
    
    subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
    
    authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer
    
    basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
    
    # Key usage: this is typical for a CA certificate. However since it will
    # prevent it being used as an test self-signed certificate it is best
    # left out by default.
    # keyUsage = cRLSign, keyCertSign
    
    # Some might want this also
    # nsCertType = sslCA, emailCA
    
    # Include email address in subject alt name: another PKIX recommendation
    # subjectAltName=email:copy
    # Copy issuer details
    # issuerAltName=issuer:copy
    
    # DER hex encoding of an extension: beware experts only!
    # obj=DER:02:03
    # Where 'obj' is a standard or added object
    # You can even override a supported extension:
    # basicConstraints= critical, DER:30:03:01:01:FF
    
    [ crl_ext ]
    
    # CRL extensions.
    # Only issuerAltName and authorityKeyIdentifier make any sense in a CRL.
    
    # issuerAltName=issuer:copy
    authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always
    
    [ proxy_cert_ext ]
    # These extensions should be added when creating a proxy certificate
    
    # This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
    # requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.
    
    basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
    
    # Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
    # the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.
    
    # This is OK for an SSL server.
    # nsCertType            = server
    
    # For an object signing certificate this would be used.
    # nsCertType = objsign
    
    # For normal client use this is typical
    # nsCertType = client, email
    
    # and for everything including object signing:
    # nsCertType = client, email, objsign
    
    # This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
    # keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
    
    # This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
    nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"
    
    # PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
    subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
    authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
    
    # This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
    # Import the email address.
    # subjectAltName=email:copy
    # An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
    # deprecated according to PKIX.
    # subjectAltName=email:move
    
    # Copy subject details
    # issuerAltName=issuer:copy
    
    #nsCaRevocationUrl      = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
    #nsBaseUrl
    #nsRevocationUrl
    #nsRenewalUrl
    #nsCaPolicyUrl
    #nsSslServerName
    
    # This really needs to be in place for it to be a proxy certificate.
    proxyCertInfo=critical,language:id-ppl-anyLanguage,pathlen:3,policy:foo
    
    ####################################################################
    [ tsa ]
    
    default_tsa = tsa_config1   # the default TSA section
    
    [ tsa_config1 ]
    
    # These are used by the TSA reply generation only.
    dir     = ./demoCA      # TSA root directory
    serial      = $dir/tsaserial    # The current serial number (mandatory)
    crypto_device   = builtin       # OpenSSL engine to use for signing
    signer_cert = $dir/tsacert.pem  # The TSA signing certificate
                        # (optional)
    certs       = $dir/cacert.pem   # Certificate chain to include in reply
                        # (optional)
    signer_key  = $dir/private/tsakey.pem # The TSA private key (optional)
    signer_digest  = sha256         # Signing digest to use. (Optional)
    default_policy  = tsa_policy1       # Policy if request did not specify it
                        # (optional)
    other_policies  = tsa_policy2, tsa_policy3  # acceptable policies (optional)
    digests     = sha1, sha256, sha384, sha512  # Acceptable message digests (mandatory)
    accuracy    = secs:1, millisecs:500, microsecs:100  # (optional)
    clock_precision_digits  = 0 # number of digits after dot. (optional)
    ordering        = yes   # Is ordering defined for timestamps?
                    # (optional, default: no)
    tsa_name        = yes   # Must the TSA name be included in the reply?
                    # (optional, default: no)
    ess_cert_id_chain   = no    # Must the ESS cert id chain be included?
                    # (optional, default: no)
    ess_cert_id_alg     = sha1  # algorithm to compute certificate
                    # identifier (optional, default: sha1)
    [default_conf]
    ssl_conf = ssl_sect
    
    [ssl_sect]
    system_default = system_default_sect
    
    [system_default_sect]
    MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
    CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
```

Does anyone have any thoughts of what i might be doing wrong or a more recent guide that i can use to get this setup?

Comment: I should add that the index.txt file doesn't seem to be updated with new certificates, only revoked ones. i assume this is correct and perhaps this is just something that has changed since the guides were written.

Answer (score 0):

OK so now i feel silly, i updated to aes256 instead of des3 using the original guide and this is working as expected now.